# How to combine 2 seperate arrays to an extensive combined list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking for it everywhere but I can't seem to find the answer although it seems an regular problem.

I'm trying to automate the duplication of cells in excel. 
I have two lists: list 1 with values 1,2,3,4 and the second list is with values a,b,c,d.
Now I want to have a file where for every value in list 1, the values in list two are duplicated in excel. So:

```
1 - a
1 - b
1 - c
1 - d
2 - a
2 - b
2 - c
2 - d
3 - a
...
```

I'm wondering if there's a function within excel or if not a macro that I could use to solve this? For this short list it is of course easy to do with autofill, but when the list consists of a few hundred values, it gets more complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be really easy to understand ...

Open VBE <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and right click VBA project. Insert a Module and copy-paste the below code. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run

```
Sub Main()

    Dim number As Range
    Dim letter As Range

    For Each number In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each letter In Range("B1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            With Sheet2
                .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = number
                .Range("B" & .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = letter
            End With
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

The above code assumes that your sheet1 looks like this

[image]

and the results will be on Sheet2 like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also with a few formulas/support columns without VBA:

Let's assume your first category is in column A, starting in A2 and your category is in column B.

1. Determine the record count for each category, e.g. in C1: `=COUNTA($A:$A)-1` (assuming a header row) and C2 equivalent
2. Place two support column, e.g. in E and F) - E will hold the row for the first category and F the Id for the second category. Place the following formula in E2: `=IF(ISTEXT(E1),1,IF(F2=1,E1+1,E1))` and this in F2: `=IF(ISTEXT(F1),1,IF(F1=$C$2,1,F1+1))`
3. Add two more columns for the final result - G for category one with formula `=INDEX(A:A,E2+1)` and H for category 2 with the formula `=INDEX(B:B,F2+1)`.
4. Now simply copy the formulas for the columns E:H down for a many rows as required (number of rows required is `=C1*C2`

In the end it'll look something like this: [image]

You can download the [file here](https://mega.co.nz/#!OFIHhA7I!SW3ScTYNd71GoqRL8UI5lTRwFcRhzoxOSSiyN9NoHTM).

Comment: @Mehow,

I tried this solution and using the step by step editor, I get an error when arriving to line with



`Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = number`



"Error 424 - Object required"
<br/><br/>
I thought is might be the sheet2 that hasn't been defined but that doesn't seem to do the trick.
Do you have any idea what might be the problem?


Thanks!

Comment: @user2962502 change `With Sheet2` to `With Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Comment: +1 for a completely different approach achieving the same result! learning new things everday, thanks for that Peter!