# Iterate over defined lists in excel

Tags: excel, list

I have an excel spreadsheet, with two defined lists.  Call them colours{red, green, blue} and types{1, 2}

I have a function to calculate for each object, so finally, I have a table that looks like

```
colour type result
```

red 1 100

red 2 200

green 1 150

green 2 250

blue 1 155

blue 2 255

But obviously I wrote that by hand.  Without using a VB script, is there any way I can get excel to fill in the colour and type cells to enumerate the whole set?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question how to create all combinations of items from two lists?

Comment: @calvin - I guess so.  If I could write a program, it would look like "for c in colour do: for t in type do: print c, t".

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525315/concatenate-permutations-between-two-columns/23526267#23526267

Comment: Also related is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284290/how-to-combine-2-seperate-arrays-to-an-extensive-combined-list-in-excel

Comment: Ok - what I needed to know is that counta and index functions existed

Answer (score 0):

Here's one VBA approach - you can pass in as many lists (by range) as you like and it will create all the combinations and copy them to where you specify.

```
Sub tester()

    'First range is where to place the results, next ranges
    '  are the lists to be combined
    SqlPermutate Sheet1.Range("E1"), Sheet1.Range("A1:A20"), _
                 Sheet1.Range("B1:B5"), Sheet1.Range("C1:C10")

End Sub


Sub SqlPermutate(rngDestination As Range, ParamArray ranges() As Variant)

    Dim oConn As Object, oRS As Object
    Dim sPath, i As Long, srcWb As Workbook
    Dim sSQL As String, flds As String, tbls As String

    'check source ranges are in a saved workbook...
    Set srcWb = ranges(0).Parent.Parent
    If srcWb.Path <> "" Then
      sPath = srcWb.FullName
    Else
      MsgBox "Workbook being queried must be saved first..."
      Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = LBound(ranges) To UBound(ranges)
        flds = flds & IIf(Len(flds) > 0, ",", "") & Chr(65 + i) & ".*"
        tbls = tbls & IIf(Len(tbls) > 0, ",", "") & _
                RngNm(ranges(i)) & " " & Chr(65 + i)
    Next i

    sSQL = "select " & flds & " from " & tbls
    Debug.Print sSQL

    Set oConn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & sPath & "';" & _
                 "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=no;IMEX=1';"

    oRS.Open sSQL, oConn

    If Not oRS.EOF Then
        rngDestination.CopyFromRecordset oRS
    Else
        MsgBox "No records found"
    End If

    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close

End Sub

Function RngNm(r) As String
    RngNm = "[" & r.Parent.Name & "$" & _
                r.Address(False, False) & "]"
End Function
```